# How could I create a docklet or Icon in the Unity

Tags: unity, icons, dock

I have think about what Dock I should install for Ubuntu. Then I think ok why should I install one there is already one on the left side. But now my question, how can I intigrate my own docklet's or create a link to a bash skript? Short question, but a long story, I think. may anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer by my self.

1) right click in the folder of the program you want to drag in your dock and create a empty file.

2) rename the file, for example like the program with the ending ".desktop" for example name.desktop

3) now open "gedit" with the terminal or with your unity.

4) drag and drop the .desktop file into gedit and copie this to it. You have to edit the parameter (Name, GenericName, Exec, Icon) you can change the Categories param if you want.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=programname
GenericName=thomething
Comment=
Type=Application
Exec=path/to/executable.file
Icon=path/to/image.file
Categories=programms;
Name[de_DE]=programname
```

5) now save the file and close gedit.

6) rightclick on the file then click on properties and make the file executeable.

7) now you can drag and drop it into the unity dock